# How to integrate Fingerprint scanner SDK with VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, fingerprint

I have bought a fingerprint scanner device **STARTEK,model:FM220** to integrate with a application which is developed in **VB.NET**. I am searching for the full fledged SDK to integrate with the application. I found the SDK from here: [SDK Startek,FM220](http://www.accesscomputech.com/download/). The SDK allows to operate few functions like **ConnectDevice, GetTemplate, GetImagequality** etc. But the function which was most important to match the user's fingerprint is to authenticate i.e function to match the ISO Template (returning in byte format) by the application.

So can anyone help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: You're probably better speaking to the manufacturer rather than coming here at this point.

Comment: Manufacturer is a Taiwan Based company. While enquiring they redirected to the Indian Technical support Team. They didn't response well on this issue. So, I m in a trouble. If anyone of you have gone through similar problem. Please suggest me what to do next

Comment: I haven't unfortunately, not in this area. It's a shame you don't have the support from them as they normally are the best course of action.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this part

```
Public Sub ScanCompleteFM220(result As FM220_Capture_Result) Implements FM220_Scanner_Interface.ScanCompleteFM220
    'HANDLE CROSS THREAD OPERATIONS.......................
    If result.getResult() Then
        Dim tmpl As String = Convert.ToBase64String(result.getISO_Template())    ' <--- THIS LINE
```

converts the result of the scan to a BASE64 string.

So you can save this string to a database during fingerprint enrolment. When validating, search for this string from your database.

Comment: Yes exactly you got it correct. There should be a chance to verify the string  if the same string returns for a unique finger print. But here the story is a bit different I guess. For the same finger print it returns different string. Don't know why. May be there is some different match function i m not able to access it