# Can I use external hardware for a VB.NET application, example: Fingerprent Sensor

Tags: vb.net, winforms, camera, fingerprint, microphone

I am developing a `winform` that has a login page of some sort. I wanted to enable more then 2 types of authorization, just incase the user forgets his/her email:password combonation. I have added phone numbers, but I am curious to know if I can add fingerprint scanners, microphones and cameras into the mix. Is there a way to do that. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384135/how-to-integrate-fingerprint-scanner-sdk-with-vb-net-application) post, but I am unsure if it works with any type of scanner, because the person who asked the question specifically named a single fingerprint scanner. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks Bye!

Comment: If you are unsure of something, go ahead, give it a try, then you post a question if it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, will try and see what happens

Comment: From fingerprint authorization, check http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html if it helps